# Gene Mapping - Please explain in Lay terms

Tags: genetics, chromosome, gene, allele

Taking an AP bio course, and for some reason I cannot comprehend the mechanism of how one determines the location of alleles on a chromosome. The math is simple and I can memorize it, but its bugging me that I don't understand a seemingly simple concept. Please explain to me like I am utterly inexperienced in biology (because for the most part, I am).

Comment: Stack Exchange isn't great for "explain this concept for me"-type questions; it's better if you can provide a specific explanation of what you understand and where you're stuck and ask a specific, directed question about that particular point. If you want a concept explained to you, better to use a textbook or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gene_mapping). If you read that Wikipedia article or your textbook, can you identify where specifically you are stuck? What's the specific concept that you need to be further explained?

Comment: thanks, I'm still new to this, so I appreciate the advice. I will be sure to be more specific on my next post.

Comment: It's the 21st century.  You want to know where a gene is located in a species that's been studied?  You look it up.

Answer (score 0):

Recombination happens every meiosis at some random location on every chromosome pair. If two loci are close on the chromosome, is unlikely that recombination happens between them, meaning they are "linked". If you look in a lot of meioses you can use the math to detect this linkage.

Gene mapping consists in considering every position in the genome, and measuring the linkage between that position and a phenotype (how frequently does recombination in meiosis separate the phenotype and the position).

Real world analogy: you measure how close two birds sitting on a telephone line are by measuring the rate at which some other bird lands between them. If they are right next to each other, then no other bird can land between them.